# Alter the letters after "ACCOUNTS\" to lower case?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update

I have a database table, `users`, with different username cases (see the example). How can I update the letters after `ACCOUNTS\` to lower case?

```
ACCOUNTS\James.McAvoy
ACCOUNTS\michael.fassbender
ACCOUNTS\nicholas.hoult
ACCOUNTS\Oscar.Isaac
```

Desired result after the update:

```
ACCOUNTS\james.mcavoy
ACCOUNTS\michael.fassbender
ACCOUNTS\nicholas.hoult
ACCOUNTS\oscar.isaac
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.[User]
SET username_column = N'ACCOUNTS' + LOWER(SUBSTRING(username_column, 9, 4000))
WHERE username_column LIKE 'ACCOUNTS\%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace and Lower should do the job here.

```
UPDATE dbo.User SET username = 'ACCOUNTS\' + LOWER(REPLACE(username, 'ACCOUNTS\', ''))
```

Comment: I added a filter because it wasn't clear to me that every single row in the table would begin with `ACCOUNTS` (I also skipped `REPLACE()`).